Can I have calculated coordinates in an svg without additional javascript?
Is is possible in svg to define coordinates relative to the boundary that dont get scaled? In this example, I have a square with an additional path inside. The coordinates of the point should be (w-1, h-1)*, regardless of the scaling. So, if the box if (0,0),(10,10) it should b at (9,9) and if the coordinates would be (2,2),(20,20) it should be at(19,19).
Is this anyhow possible in svg?


*yes, that really should be x2,y2.

You'd need javascript.

wild thought; use SVG SMIL animations

The shape inside, that is a path connected to bottom/left and top/right, is that always the case? If the shape was a circle it could be positioned using CSS calc, if you could live without a viewBox attribute on the SVG element. But that is a lot of conditions and we would need to know more about the context.

If you're aiming at the actual polygon shape you may also use CSS clip-path functions like polygon() as it supports relative and calculated vertex values

Your question is not very clear. How would you like to draw the "additional path inside"?
This is a possible answer.

You begin your path at the furthest point (in this case M22,22)

you draw the shape (in this case L22,2 L2,2 L2,22 z )

once reached the starting point you move inwards 1 unit in x and in y (m-1,-1). Please note the lowercase command m for relative coordinates.

you repeat the commands for the shape (in this case L22,2 L2,2 L2,22 z )




<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" stroke="black" stroke-width=".2" fill="none">
  <path d="M22,22  L22,2 L2,2 L2,22 z 
           m-1,-1  L22,2 L2,2 L2,22 z" />
</svg>




Thats a nice idea, but it doesnt work. A transform still changes the inner distance from the corner.
